# Getting the same error message in a typescript reply bot

Tags: typescript, api, twitter

Trying to make a bot the will reply when a tweet containing a certain hashtag is created. Whenever I try to run the code, I get the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\src\index.ts:16:48
    at C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:127:13
    at onRequestComplete (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:352:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:364:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
[ERROR] 18:14:08 TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

I think it's probably something to do with the replyName part. Here is my code, help appreciated :)

```
import Twit, { Response } from 'twit';

const Twitter = new Twit(require('./config'));

const mediaArtsSearch: Twit.Params = {
  q: '#100DaysOfCode',
  count: 100,
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
  result_type: 'recent',
};

const retweetLatest = () => {
  Twitter.get('search/tweets', mediaArtsSearch, (error: Error, data: any) => {
    console.log(error, data);
    if (!error) {         
      const replyName = data.statuses[0].tweet.user.screen_name;//find name of user
      const replyId = data.statuses[0].id_str;     //finds id of tweet, labels it as retweetid
      Twitter.post(
        'statuses/update/',{in_reply_to_status_id: replyId, status: '@' + replyName
             //replies the tweet
        },                                                                 
        (error: Error, response: Response) => {
          if (response) {
            console.log(
              'Success! Check your bot, it should have retweeted something.',
            );
          }
          if (error) {
            console.log('There was an error with Twitter:', error);
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      console.log('There was an error with your hashtag search:', error);
    }
  });
};

retweetLatest();
setInterval(retweetLatest, 1000 * 20);
```

Comment: does `data.statuses[0].tweet` contain anything?

Comment: [api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start/recent-search) seems to indicate this isn't the structure of the response

Comment: I don't know, i just put it there because i had to put it there when retrieving the if of the tweet. I should also mention I've never used this API before and am a total beginner.